# Retrieve value of most recently SelectedItem from multi-select listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, multi-select

How can I retrieve the value of a clicked item in a multi-select listbox?

Currently, if I click one item and use lstBox.SelectedValue, it will return the proper value; however, if I then click on another item, I am still shown the first item's value.

Basically, I want the value of the item most recently clicked on, regardless of whether or not it is the SelectedValue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a multiple selection listbox, you can get a collection of all the selected items by using [SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems.aspx) instead of [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem.aspx).

If you need to know the sequence in which the items were selected, or which was selected most recently, I think you would need to record if yourself by [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event.

Answer (score 1):

The SelectedIndexChanged handler will get called when you select/unselect an item in the listbox.

However, it doesn't indicate which one was selected/unselected.

```
listbox1.SelectedItems
```

will contain the currently selected items and you could internally keep track of which index was most recently added.